# Alternative to <content> tag in HTML5?

Tags: html

I was reading today about Shadow DOM, where the author used this `<content>` tag to pull in `textContent` from the host.

**Tutorial**: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/

When I looked it up, I found that the `<content>` tag has been deprecated and should be avoided. What should I do now? Should I learn to use `<content>` tag or not?
**Source**:  [Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Content)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same documentation ([Mozilla FireFox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Content))) states:

> It has now been replaced by the `<slot>` element.

Use the `<slot>` element. When something is deprecated, you should no longer use it. ([Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Content)) also states this.) Deprecated means it is no longer approved of/disapproved.

Comment: I almost missed that part.

Comment: @RajatSaxena if this answer solved your issue, please make sure to click the up-arrow and the checkmark.

Comment: It seems like <slot> is not working as of now in Chrome. But, yours is a correct answer.

Comment: @RajatSaxena Are you sure? Have you replaced all `<content>` tags with `<slot>` tags?